# Website navbar animation stops working after using JavaScript http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, httprequest

I am working on a client's static website. That is not mainly what I do for him, but I do have some skill in that area, so I am helping out. So thanks for your patience with me. I have used HTTP requests with jQuery on my own static website to pull in nav.html and footer.html content on all my pages so I don't need duplicate HTML in every file and to simplify any updates. On my site, I'm getting it with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadContent();
});

function loadContent(){
    $('nav').load('nav.html');
    $('footer').load('footer.html');
}
```

and on his I needed to get it with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadContent();
});

function loadContent(){
    $('header').load('nav.html');
    $('footer').load('footer.html');
}
```

because he has more than one set of navigation controls surrounded by nav tags in the navbar. I can load the content fine just like on my own website, the text colors and layout are preserved, and there are zero problems with the footer. However, some things in the nav bar stop working. While the navbar itself is static, when you scroll to the top of the page, it has a transparent background. When you scroll down, a colored background fades in with a nice animation behind the navigation links so that the main content doesn't obscure the navigation links. In addition, at any window size, there is always the hamburger menu that opens a full-screen overlay with the nav links in list style.

When I started using the .load function to bring in this content, both the navbar bg animation and being able to click on the hamburger menu to open the optional overlay menu stopped working.

In his HTML files, the CSS is all imported in the  and the JavaScript files are all brought in right before . My document ready function above is imported as the 2nd to last of many other JS files. We're using jQuery 2.1.3.

Any ideas as to why the animation and overlay menu might have stopped working once I implemented these functions?

I started trying to narrow down which of the CSS or JS plug-ins might be responsible for the navbar bg fade-in, and I think it has to do with bootstrap.

If it's hard to tell why it's not working, I'd like to know if there's a way for me to "force" those things to work by maybe reimporting something onto the separated nav.html file that's being pulled in. I tried reloading certain JS files into that HTML file, but the console said it was "junk." Aside from that, I haven't gotten any other console errors that have helped me.

The CSS imported into the head:

```
<!-- Plugins -->
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/simpletextrotator.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/superslides.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/vertical.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Template core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The HTML in the navbar:

```
<header>
    <!-- OVERLAY MENU -->
    <div id="overlay-menu" class="overlay-menu">
        <a href="#" id="overlay-menu-hide" class="navigation-hide"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></a>
        <div class="overlay-menu-inner">
            <nav class="overlay-menu-nav">
                <ul id="nav">   
                    <span class="font-alt">Navigation:</span>
                    <li><a href="index.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="concerts.html">Concerts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sheetmusic.html">Sheet Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <br>
                    <span class="font-alt">Resources:</span>
                    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="downloads/ChristopherTin_EPK.zip">EPK and Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pressarchives.html">Press Archives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="credits.html">Full Credits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-navigation-footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <p class="copyright font-alt m-b-0"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /OVERLAY MENU -->

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://facebook.com/christophertinmusic" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://twitter.com/christophertin" target="_blank">
                    <i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://instagram.com/christophertinmusic" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/tinworks" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
                    </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://soundcloud.com/christophertin" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i>
                    </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /SOCIAL ICONS -->
            <!-- ICONS NAVBAR -->
            <ul id="icons-navbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="toggle-menu" class="show-overlay" title="Menu">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /ICONS NAVBAR -->
            <!-- MAIN PAGES -->
            <ul class="extra-navbar nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-dark">

                <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" title="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="music.html" title="Music">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="concerts.html" title="Concerts">Concerts</a></li>
                <li><a href="sheetmusic.html">Sheet Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="store.html" title="Store">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /MAIN PAGES -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /NAVIGATION -->
</header>
```

The JavaScript imported just before :

```
<!-- Javascript files -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.superslides.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/appear.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="assets/js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/contact.js"></script>
<!--<script src="assets/js/loadNavFooter.js"></script>  -->
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

I'm commenting out loadNavFooter because I'm in the middle of troubleshooting.

There's a ton of stuff in the bootstrap.js file about scrolling (and I am weakest at JavaScript. I'm not sure if this bit is helpful, but here's an excerpt:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: modal.js v3.3.6
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
  // ======================

  var Modal = function (element, options) {
    this.options             = options
    this.$body               = $(document.body)
    this.$element            = $(element)
    this.$dialog             = this.$element.find('.modal-dialog')
    this.$backdrop           = null
    this.isShown             = null
    this.originalBodyPad     = null
    this.scrollbarWidth      = 0
    this.ignoreBackdropClick = false

    if (this.options.remote) {
      this.$element
        .find('.modal-content')
        .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
          this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
        }, this))
    }
  }

  Modal.VERSION  = '3.3.6'

  Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION = 300
  Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION = 150

  Modal.DEFAULTS = {
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true,
    show: true
  }

  Modal.prototype.toggle = function (_relatedTarget) {
    return this.isShown ? this.hide() : this.show(_relatedTarget)
  }

  Modal.prototype.show = function (_relatedTarget) {
    var that = this
    var e    = $.Event('show.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = true

    this.checkScrollbar()
    this.setScrollbar()
    this.$body.addClass('modal-open')

    this.escape()
    this.resize()

    this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', $.proxy(this.hide, this))

    this.$dialog.on('mousedown.dismiss.bs.modal', function () {
      that.$element.one('mouseup.dismiss.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(that.$element)) that.ignoreBackdropClick = true
      })
    })

    this.backdrop(function () {
      var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

      if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
        that.$element.appendTo(that.$body) // don't move modals dom position
      }

      that.$element
        .show()
        .scrollTop(0)

      that.adjustDialog()

      if (transition) {
        that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      }

      that.$element.addClass('in')

      that.enforceFocus()

      var e = $.Event('shown.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })

      transition ?
        that.$dialog // wait for modal to slide in
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
            that.$element.trigger('focus').trigger(e)
          })
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        that.$element.trigger('focus').trigger(e)
    })
  }

  Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault()

    e = $.Event('hide.bs.modal')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = false

    this.escape()
    this.resize()

    $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal')

    this.$element
      .removeClass('in')
      .off('click.dismiss.bs.modal')
      .off('mouseup.dismiss.bs.modal')

    this.$dialog.off('mousedown.dismiss.bs.modal')

    $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      this.$element
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
      this.hideModal()
  }

  Modal.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
    $(document)
      .off('focusin.bs.modal') // guard against infinite focus loop
      .on('focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length) {
          this.$element.trigger('focus')
        }
      }, this))
  }

  Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
    if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
      this.$element.on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        e.which == 27 && this.hide()
      }, this))
    } else if (!this.isShown) {
      this.$element.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal')
    }
  }

  Modal.prototype.resize = function () {
    if (this.isShown) {
      $(window).on('resize.bs.modal', $.proxy(this.handleUpdate, this))
    } else {
      $(window).off('resize.bs.modal')
    }
  }

  Modal.prototype.hideModal = function () {
    var that = this
    this.$element.hide()
    this.backdrop(function () {
      that.$body.removeClass('modal-open')
      that.resetAdjustments()
      that.resetScrollbar()
      that.$element.trigger('hidden.bs.modal')
    })
  }

  Modal.prototype.removeBackdrop = function () {
    this.$backdrop && this.$backdrop.remove()
    this.$backdrop = null
  }

  Modal.prototype.backdrop = function (callback) {
    var that = this
    var animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

    if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
      var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

      this.$backdrop = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .addClass('modal-backdrop ' + animate)
        .appendTo(this.$body)

      this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        if (this.ignoreBackdropClick) {
          this.ignoreBackdropClick = false
          return
        }
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return
        this.options.backdrop == 'static'
          ? this.$element[0].focus()
          : this.hide()
      }, this))

      if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow

      this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

      if (!callback) return

      doAnimate ?
        this.$backdrop
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', callback)
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        callback()

    } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
      this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

      var callbackRemove = function () {
        that.removeBackdrop()
        callback && callback()
      }
      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
        this.$backdrop
          .one('bsTransitionEnd', callbackRemove)
          .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
        callbackRemove()

    } else if (callback) {
      callback()
    }
  }

  // these following methods are used to handle overflowing modals

  Modal.prototype.handleUpdate = function () {
    this.adjustDialog()
  }

  Modal.prototype.adjustDialog = function () {
    var modalIsOverflowing = this.$element[0].scrollHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight

    this.$element.css({
      paddingLeft:  !this.bodyIsOverflowing && modalIsOverflowing ? this.scrollbarWidth : '',
      paddingRight: this.bodyIsOverflowing && !modalIsOverflowing ? this.scrollbarWidth : ''
    })
  }

  Modal.prototype.resetAdjustments = function () {
    this.$element.css({
      paddingLeft: '',
      paddingRight: ''
    })
  }

  Modal.prototype.checkScrollbar = function () {
    var fullWindowWidth = window.innerWidth
    if (!fullWindowWidth) { // workaround for missing window.innerWidth in IE8
      var documentElementRect = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
      fullWindowWidth = documentElementRect.right - Math.abs(documentElementRect.left)
    }
    this.bodyIsOverflowing = document.body.clientWidth < fullWindowWidth
    this.scrollbarWidth = this.measureScrollbar()
  }

  Modal.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {
    var bodyPad = parseInt((this.$body.css('padding-right') || 0), 10)
    this.originalBodyPad = document.body.style.paddingRight || ''
    if (this.bodyIsOverflowing) this.$body.css('padding-right', bodyPad + this.scrollbarWidth)
  }

  Modal.prototype.resetScrollbar = function () {
    this.$body.css('padding-right', this.originalBodyPad)
  }

  Modal.prototype.measureScrollbar = function () { // thx walsh
    var scrollDiv = document.createElement('div')
    scrollDiv.className = 'modal-scrollbar-measure'
    this.$body.append(scrollDiv)
    var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth
    this.$body[0].removeChild(scrollDiv)
    return scrollbarWidth
  }


  // MODAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // =======================

  function Plugin(option, _relatedTarget) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.modal')
      var options = $.extend({}, Modal.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option](_relatedTarget)
      else if (options.show) data.show(_relatedTarget)
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.modal

  $.fn.modal             = Plugin
  $.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal


  // MODAL NO CONFLICT
  // =================

  $.fn.modal.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.modal = old
    return this
  }


  // MODAL DATA-API
  // ==============

  $(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this)
    var href    = $this.attr('href')
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) // strip for ie7
    var option  = $target.data('bs.modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())

    if ($this.is('a')) e.preventDefault()

    $target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {
      if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return // only register focus restorer if modal will actually get shown
      $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
      })
    })
    Plugin.call($target, option, this)
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug it to see if it is code related.

Another possibility is something transparent covering the menu - I had such a problem where a modal would actually after dismissing become just invisible and block some buttons.

Other than this without code to look at is hard to say.